# Replicating iOS7 Style gaussian blur?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, drawing, ios7, blur

I'm drawing a circle as below which I'm filling with a block colour but ideally I'd like to replicate the iOS7 style blur, especially as it sits on top of a photo.

I've looked into the various ways of doing this but they all involve a UIImage whereas this is a circle which I'm drawing. Any way to do this?

```
    - (void)drawCenter:(CGContextRef)contextRef withViewSize:(CGSize)viewSize andCenter:(CGPoint)center
{
    int innerDiameter = viewSize.width - self.thickness;
    float innerRadius = innerDiameter / 2;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, self.thickness);
    CGRect innerCircle = CGRectMake(center.x - innerRadius, center.y - innerRadius,
                                    innerDiameter, innerDiameter);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(contextRef, innerCircle);
    CGContextClip(contextRef);
    CGContextClearRect(contextRef, innerCircle);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, self.centerColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(contextRef, innerCircle);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the final effect you're looking for? Are you blurring the whole image behind the circle? Or do you want to present a circle on top of an image for which there is a slight translucency within the circle where you can see a hint of the blurred background image, but otherwise leaving the rest of the image unblurred?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes sure, this is the sort of thing I'm after so it's basically blurring the circle view itself rather than the image behind: http://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/125948/screenshots/1210251/live-blur.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do the blur, but clip the results (e.g. with `CGContextClip`) to the path drawn by the circle. The following code blur a circle in an image, increasing its luminosity by 10%:

```
UIImage *original = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

UIImage *imageWithBlurredCircle = [original imageWithBlurredCircleWithCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)
                                                                      radius:75
                                                                        blur:10
                                                                  luminosity:0.1];
```

Clearly, if you don't want to change luminosity, pass `0` for the `luminosity` adjustment. Or if you want to decrease the luminosity by 10%, pass `-0.1`

Anyway, the following `UIImage` category renders the final images is as follows:

```
#import "UIImage+Blur.h"
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@implementation UIImage (Blur)

- (UIImage *)imageWithBlurredCircleWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)circleRadius blur:(CGFloat)blurRadius luminosity:(CGFloat)luminosity
{
    UIImage *blurredImage = [self imageWithBlur:blurRadius luminosity:luminosity];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // if you don't want to include the original image, exclude the next five lines

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // clip the drawing to the blurred circle

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, circleRadius, 0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, blurredImage.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // now save the image

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithBlur:(CGFloat)radius luminosity:(CGFloat)luminosity
{
    CIImage *inputImage  = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage]; // self.CIImage;
    CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIImage *blurImage   = [self blurCIImage:inputImage radius:radius];
    CIImage *outputImage = [self changeLuminosityOfCIImage:blurImage luminosity:luminosity];

    // note, adjust rect because blur changed size of image

    CGRect rect          = [outputImage extent];
    rect.origin.x        += (rect.size.width  - self.size.width ) / 2;
    rect.origin.y        += (rect.size.height - self.size.height) / 2;
    rect.size            = self.size;

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:rect];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    CGImageRelease(cgimg);

    return image;
}

- (CIImage *)blurCIImage:(CIImage *)inputImage radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    if (radius == 0)
        return inputImage;

    CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [blurFilter setDefaults];
    [blurFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [blurFilter setValue:@(radius) forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

    return [blurFilter outputImage];
}

- (CIImage *)changeLuminosityOfCIImage:(CIImage *)inputImage luminosity:(CGFloat)luminosity
{
    if (luminosity == 0)
        return inputImage;

    NSParameterAssert(luminosity >= -1.0 && luminosity <= 1.0);

    CIFilter *toneCurveFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIToneCurve"];
    [toneCurveFilter setDefaults];
    [toneCurveFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    if (luminosity > 0)
    {
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0  Y:luminosity]                           forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.25 Y:luminosity + 0.25 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.50 Y:luminosity + 0.50 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint2"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.75 Y:luminosity + 0.75 * (1 - luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint3"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1.0  Y:1.0]                                  forKey:@"inputPoint4"];
    }
    else
    {
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0  Y:0.0]                     forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.25 Y:0.25 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.50 Y:0.50 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint2"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.75 Y:0.75 * (1 + luminosity)] forKey:@"inputPoint3"];
        [toneCurveFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1.0  Y:1 + luminosity]          forKey:@"inputPoint4"];
    }

    return [toneCurveFilter outputImage];
}

@end
```

---

Alternatively, if you go to the [WWDC 2013 sample code](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013) (paid developer subscription required) and download `iOS_UIImageEffects`, you can then grab the `UIImage+ImageEffects` category. That provides a few new methods:

```
- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;
- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage;
```

So, to blur and image and lightening it (giving that "frosted glass" effect) you can then do:

```
UIImage *newImage = [image applyLightEffect];
```

Interestingly, Apple's code does not employ `CIFilter`, but rather calls [`vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_convolution/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005489-CH210-vImageConvolve_ARGB8888) of the [vImage high-performance image processing framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001001).

This technique is illustrated in WWDC 2013 video [Implementing Engaging UI on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=226#226).

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a go when I get in later, thanks for your time.